# grid.arrange all columns of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm saving an arbitrary number of random samples in a data frame:

```
sigmas = 1:5
xs = sapply(sigmas, function (v) rrayleigh(size, v))
mat = matrix(xs, ncol = length(sigmas), dimnames = list(NULL, sigmas))
df = data.frame(mat)
```

Now I want to save a histogram for each column and later plot it using `grid.arrange()`. After calling

```
ps = sapply(df, function (v) qplot(x = v))
p = qplot(df$X1)
```

`p` produces a histogram, while `ps$X1` outputs `NULL`. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: another way to proceed is to reshape the data to long ( melt)and then use factets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I recommend using `lapply` instead of `sapply`)

You can change:

```
ps = sapply(df, function (v) qplot(x = v))
```

to:

```
library(iterators)
ps = lapply(iter(df,by="col"), function(v) qplot(v))
```

or:

```
ps = lapply(1:ncol(df), function(v) qplot(df[,v]))
```

Your issue was that you supplied the entire data frame at once.